# cPanel Moving mails to another host

Tags: email, accounts

I need to transfer about 20 addon domains and their email accounts to new host where I already have some sites, mail accounts, databases etc..

For some reason, I think that my best bet is to transfer mail account manually like: copying **etc** and **mail** folder from old to new host via FTP.. Now while this works very well, I have one problem. All transferred mails again have ***unread flag*** (like there are never opened).

Is there a way to move mail accounts while in same way preserve read/unread flags?

Comment: Using the built in migration and backup functions of cpanel is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) or similar other software to move the mail between non-identical mail systems.

If the mail systems are *identical*, then moving the data (ideally, rsync over ssh or similar transport) will work. You've goofed somewhere, probably by using FTP.